# FETCH NOT NULL VALUES FROM MULTIPLE COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to retrieve Columns that are not null (not Checking Nullability), from multiple columns that I've in my sql server table.

I have a table over 20 columns, and I want to retrieve columns that are not null for each record. I tried using not null in the where condition, but that won't work. I also visited [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecgqu.png) but it isn't work either.

My table structure looks as follow:

Expected output is: all 1's for each ID.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a sample result that you are expecting? With your sample data, you want to not get Col2 in your query result? Sorry, it's not quite clear what you want to see in the end with that sample data.

Comment: For instance, for ID = 101 I want to get values from Col1, Col3, Col4 and Col5
For Id = 102, since all are null then It'd not return any result-sets. For ID=103, I want to get only Col3

Comment: Logic that you expected is fine, Can you attach the expected result structure for the above one?

Comment: @Arulmouzhi If I want to get for ID - 101,
   SELECT * FROM tmpTable
   WHERE (---here I want to exclude the null cols, if found)
So my output will be as;
-----------------------------------------
ID   Col1 Col3 Col4 Col5
-----------------------------------------
101  1       1       1      1

Comment: so, the most records you would ever get back are 1 record; correct? if you want to query a dynamic set of columns (depending on nulls in the columns) then you would only be able to return one row in each execution of the query. Just making sure I am seeing that correctly. I must say that helping you define a query is doable,but I have LOTS of questions about why this is needed. What will consume these results? What is before and after this query? Why must the results be presented this way? I suspect there is something I would much rather change before or after than do this query.

Comment: @jamie I'm actually fetching Check box values stored in a table from a website, and send it back to another application(only the checked boxes) so that they'll display customer selections accordingly.

Comment: and so, is it true that you will only query 1 row at a time? You cannot send ID 101 and ID 103 in the same result, correct? Different number of columns returned in each case. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query which would help you to find all non NULL columns: -

```
DECLARE @sqlstr VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT    @sqlstr = COALESCE(@sqlstr + '+ ', '') + 'case ISNULL(COUNT(' + c.name + '), 0) WHEN 0 THEN '''' ELSE '',' + c.name + ''' END'
FROM    sys.all_columns c
INNER    JOIN
        sys.all_objects o
        ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE    o.name='table_name'
set @sqlstr = '
declare @innerquery2 VARCHAR(MAX)
select @innerquery2 = ' + @sqlstr + ' from table_name
SET @innerquery2 =  case when charindex('','',@innerquery2,0) =1 then right(@innerquery2, len(@innerquery2)-1) else @innerquery2 end
set @innerquery2 = ''select '' + @innerquery2 + '' from table_name Where ID=1''
print @innerquery2
exec(@innerquery2)
'
exec(@sqlstr)
```

Comment: This fetches no data whenever there's a null column (at least one NULL) in the records.

Comment: You need to change the filter condition as well along with table_name ...."Where ID=1". I just given as random.